# fsm with gevent with its own (infinite) call stack

Tags: python, gevent, automata, greenlets

I was wondering how can I define a finite state machine which has loops using a greenlet in python without causing a stckoverflow.

From https://greenlet.readthedocs.org/en/latest/:

"A “greenlet” is a small independent pseudo-thread. Think about it as a small stack of frames; the outermost (bottom) frame is the initial function you called, and the innermost frame is the one in which the greenlet is currently paused. You work with greenlets by creating a number of such stacks and jumping execution between them. Jumps are never implicit: a greenlet must choose to jump to another greenlet, which will cause the former to suspend and the latter to resume where it was suspended. Jumping between greenlets is called “switching”."

I understand that I will need to change states and that I can have an FSM like the one shown in the image:
[image: from a post I was reading]

How do I ensure that I do not hit a stack overflow in such a case?
Since greenlet only gives me a 'small stack of frames', I am skeptical about using it.

Is there an fsm design paradigm that needs to be followed here which can help is going back to earlier stack frames?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

I read a little more on the problem and it seems that I should be using Exception and try..except, which will not result in another function call, and hence avoid stackoverflow.
From: https://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html

================================

Why is there no goto?

You can use exceptions to provide a “structured goto” that even works across function calls. Many feel that exceptions can conveniently emulate all reasonable uses of the “go” or “goto” constructs of C, Fortran, and other languages.

For example:

class label: pass  # declare a label

```
try:
     ...
     if condition: raise label()  # goto label
     ...
except label:  # where to goto
     pass
```

=========================================